# Registering a C# DLL using WIX

Tags: c#, wix, wix3.5

I have a C# dll which has to go into the registry using WIX code/msi and I should be able to access the registered dll in the "Add Reference" dialog of Visual studio after running the msi.How can I accomplish this using WIX 3.5? And I'm using visual studio 2010

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom action to achieve this.

[This](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/qtexec.htm) explains how to create a custom action the executes in quiet mode. Add something similar to following:

```
gacutil /i yourdll.dll
```

in the Value attribute of Property tag.